# How to get sorting complete/finished event of jsgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I have 2 different jsGrid table.I have to update the other table data after finishing sorting event of 1st table.I searched the documentation but i couldn't find any complete/finished event for sorting.I found `onDataLoaded` event,but it does not fire after filtering.
How would i find the completion of sorting event.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the event which gets fired as the data of a grid changes - `onRefreshed`. Link - [documentation link](http://js-grid.com/docs/#onrefreshed) It gives out the grid instance as a argument.

Inside that I used `var sorting = $("#grid").jsGrid("getSorting");` 
to get the sorting which gives - 
`{
    field,      // the name of the field by which grid is sorted
    order       // 'asc' or 'desc' depending on sort order
}`.

If the table has been sorted the object will have the details - `{field:'A',order:'asc'}` if not then `{field:undefined,order:undefined}`.

`onRefreshed: function (args) {
var sorting = $("#jsgrid").jsGrid("getSorting");
}`